# 'UIFont' is not convertible to 'UIFont?'

Tags: swift, xcode7

So I had updated my XCode to 7.3 today evening.

In one of my projects, I get the following error for few labels where I set the font:

```
'(name: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont' is not convertible to '(name: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont?'
```

**EDIT:** This is my code for Title View in Navigation Bar:

```
let aTitleFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, aHeaderTitleSubtitleView.frame.midY / 2, 200, 24)
let aTitleView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: aTitleFrame)
aTitleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
aTitleView.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15) // ERROR POPS UP HERE
aTitleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
aTitleView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This is my code for an Attributed String for a UILabel:

```
let aAttributedFundLabel: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Raising\n$ \(fund)")
aAttributedFundLabel.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGrayColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 7))
aAttributedFundLabel.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 7)) // ERROR POPS UP HERE 
aAttributedFundLabel.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range: NSRange(location: 8, length: fund.characters.count + 2))
aAttributedFundLabel.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 16)!, range: NSRange(location: 8, length: fund.characters.count + 2)) // ERROR POPS UP HERE
startupFund.attributedText = aAttributedFundLabel
```

This happens only in two files in my entire project.

I opened up another project, but I was able to build and run it without any errors, even though I do set the font for multiple labels there as well.

Any idea why this is happening?

TIA!

Comment: It would help if you would show the actual code.

Comment: Edited the question with the actual code

Comment: Cool, thanks for doing that.

Comment: Sorry but what on earth is an Attributed Label? Is this some third-party thing? If so, I'd suggest there's a bug in it.

Comment: Sorry. I meant Attributed String for a UILabel. Edited the question. Uploaded only the part where I set the font.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using your code on Xcode 7.3.  Is `aAttributedFundLabel` an `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: @JAL Yes, it is an NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: Try quitting Xcode and clearing out the DerivedData caches. (Might be a good idea to restart the computer too.) If that doesn't fix it, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem either. Please copy/paste the original code and point to the line with error.

Comment: @matt Tried doing all that. Didn't help! :( Maybe I should try filing a bug.

Comment: @Eiko Copy/pasted entire code with comment line where error occurs

Comment: The real problem is that it sounds like you can't reproduce this. You will need to send Apple a reproducible example.

Comment: Oooooh ooooh I had an idea. Does the problem occur only with your Roboto-Regular? What if you change that code to a built-in font?

Comment: you are calling a string `aAttributedFundLabel`? Ada Lovelace's ghost is punishing you…

Comment: same issue here...

Comment: @zumzum can you give more details on what you're seeing?

Comment: ha, this one is a bizarre one, I saw a radar posted to the Xcode team... go figure.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Elsewhere on SO, someone suggest that where you have this:

```
aTitleView.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
```

...you should try writing this:

```
aTitleView.font = UIFont.init(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)
```

I can take no credit for this (because **I can't reproduce the bug**) so I'm just guessing! But it would be very interesting to know if it actually works.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. What really gets me is that _I can't reproduce this!_ I am dying to experience this problem for myself. Please, please, file a bug with Apple if you can _possibly_ make a reproducible example.

Comment: Will definitely do that matt! :D

Comment: Had the same issue, I'm setting this inside a lazy var instantiation; doing it outside works without the init.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me. Sticking to the UIFontDescriptor approach for now.

Comment: @zumzum I just wish I could even _have_ this problem! I'm totally unable to reproduce it.

Comment: ha, this one is a bizarre one, I saw a radar posted to the Xcode team... go figure

Comment: Worked for me, double upvote if I could. Hate fighting the compiler in these cases. Xcode 7.3 stable (7D175) / El Capitan 11.4

Comment: Thanks +matt, I'm not really surprise if you can't reproduce this bug, because I have 2 files with this code and the error just appeared in one of them.. really weird..

Comment: this fixed the issue for me as well :) the code is taking place it a lazy var and the Xcode 7.3 started marking it with an error diagnostic at some point for no reason

Comment: Thanks, but strange!!, the same code is working in my one VC and throwing error on another VC.

Comment: Oh, Come on!
If every objects are initializing without `.init` then why should this like this?

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, the Build target of my app was working forever, but when I went to Archive it for Release… I encountered this issue. Adding `.init(` resolved it.

Comment: thx for the fix! -- the issue repros only in archive mode for me

Comment: Fixed it for me! Was only getting the issue when doing an archive.

Comment: Fix working for me too, never had issue with this before i have no idea where this is coming from.

Comment: This did it for me. Using Xcode 8.2 (8C38)... Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem as well. What fixed it for me was to turn off Whole Module Optimization.

Bulid Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level

I had set it to Fastest (Whole Module Optimization). When I set it to None I didn't have this problem anymore. For context, this is a mixed code base with both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Ditto. Same as me. I could only produce this error when archiving my project. Building+running in debug mode was error-free. So, of course, I looked at my debug/release optimizations and tested Fast(WMO) vs. Fast[-O]. That did the trick, but I want to keep WMO for performance reasons, so I'll be using `UIFont.init(name:` for the time being.

Comment: `UIFont.init` also doesn't work for me, have to turn it to single file optimization, curse old code

Comment: Is there any option to use Fast(WMO) and use UIFont() together?

Comment: Xcode sucks, seriously, even disabling optimization it still happens. I "admired" Apple till I started to code with Xcode and I know a bunch of very different platforms

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and doing this allows me to compile again:

```
let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10.0)
label.font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 10.0)
```

So, use the UIFontDescriptor ...

Also doing this works for me:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 10) {
    label.font = font
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply zumzum! :)