# Swift optional issue

Tags: swift, option-type

I am getting following error in compiler -

`(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> GMSMarker`
 is not convertible to `(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> GMSMarker!`.

Please help me to resolve it.

The code that gives this error is -

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(latitudeVal!)!, longitude: Double(longitudeVal!)!)
let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: location)
```

Where `latitudeVal` & `longitudeVal` are string values from server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `if let`? like: `if let foo = (position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {//code}`

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) that I co-wrote on how to safely deal with optionals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of the Swift compiler optimization. See ['UIFont' is not convertible to 'UIFont?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163273/uifont-is-not-convertible-to-uifont).

To fix this, you can turn off 'Whole Module Optimization' in Build Settings -> Optimization Level -> (Debug/Release).

Alternatively, you can instead change your code to the following without turning off the 'Whole Module Optimization'.

```
let locationMarker = GMSMarker.init(position: location)
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below code, its working fine at my side.

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((latitudeVal as NSString).doubleValue, (longitudeVal as NSString).doubleValue)
let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: location)
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have tried all of the above methods, none worked. I have the same code in 3 places and it shows compiler error on 2 places. I don't understand whats wrong. The latitude,longitude values are accessed from models - eg.city.lat. In 3 places 3 different models are used.

Answer (score 0):

the equation `let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: location)`, left of equation is type of `GMSMarker!`, right of the equation is type of `GMSMarker`. So you can not assign the right to the left。
you can change like `let locationMarker: GMSMarker  = GMSMarker(position: location)` or `let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: location)!`. you can try.

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap your optionals.

```
    guard let long = longitudeVal else {
        print("No longitude provided")
        return
    }

    guard let lat = latitudeVal else {
        print("No latitude provided")
        return
    }

    guard let longVal = Double(long) else {
        print("Longitude contains an invalid value")
        return
    }

    guard let latVal = Double(lat) else {
        print("Latitude contains an invalid value")
        return
    }

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: location)
```

Take a look at [Early Exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i solved it :) :-

let locationMarker = GMSMarker()
locationMarker.position = location

Hope it won't make any difference in the working of the code.

Thank you all!